# Laravel authenticated user logout error

Tags: laravel, authentication, logout

tried to implement a simple user register/login function on my site using the laravel default controllers (auth/password), but as soon as I login, the class RedirectIfAuthenticated handle function prevents all access to auth url's, thus I cannot logout anymore. Is there a bug and I need to write an exception on the handle function or have I missed something?
Here is how the class looks like by default:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        //dd($next($request));
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/articles');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AuthController`'s constructor should look similar to this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

The `guest` middleware is handled by the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` class and, in order to have the *logout* functionality working, you should choose one:

- call the `logout` method from your `AuthController`.
- call whichever method you use for logout and exclude it in `AuthController`'s constructor:

  ```
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => '<whichever_method>']);
  }
  ```

Comment: This solution applies for Laravel 5+. If you're using Laravel, think in filters instead of middlewares. I think the solution should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)

Comment: This totally helped by focusing me on the `'except'` key. My controller action was `getLogout()`, so the middleware was preventing logout. Changed the middleware to `getLogout` and success!

Answer (score 0):

For potentially more-advanced reasons and needs, I will show a different idea.

Inside any middleware, a person could implement their own `except` list. Here is a reference:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CustomThing
    protected $except = [
        'api/logout',
        'api/refresh',
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach ($this->except as $excluded_route) {
            if ($request->path() === $excluded_route) {
                \Log::debug("Skipping $excluded_route in this middleware...");

                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        \Log::debug('Doing middleware stuff... '. $request->url());

    }

}
```

I will leave it up to imagination to extend that to support other types of URLs. For example, investigate matchers such as `$request->url()`, `$request->fullUrl()`, and `$request->is('admin/*')`.

A person could investigate the vendor code for the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware and make their custom one support something like this:

```
    protected $except = [
        'api/logout',
        'api/refresh',
        'foo/*',
        'http://www.external.com/links',
    ];
```

If you want it to be a reuseable solution, make that matching algorithm a Trait and import it into any middleware you want to exclude routes from.